# what is the solid plane in cannon.js?

Tags: three.js, physics-engine, bulletphysics, cannon.js

I drop any three.js objects on the cannon.js plane and I want them to bounce.
but I am struggling to understand below z=0 and 'solid'.
Here's my visaulization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXa2p.png)

`floorBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(-1, 0, 0), Math.PI/2)`
I don't think it should work based on my understanding, but somehow it still works.

I expect `floorBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(-1, 0, 0), -Math.PI/2)`
By my understanding, the plane is xy aligned and -Math.PI/2 will do 90 degrees clockwise rotation.
Because of infinite plane for negative z axis direction, 'solid' part should face negative y direction in order to make objects bounce on the plane.